# Send mail from localhost

Tags: php, xampp, gmail

I want to know if it is possible to send emails from localhost. If yes, how? I want to send emails from my localhost using my gmail account. I have a Mac OS X Yosemite Version 10.10.1 and I am running XAMPP 5.6.3-0.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to configure XAMPP to send mail from localhost?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965376/how-to-configure-xampp-to-send-mail-from-localhost)

Comment: Try using something like PHPMailer http://phpmailer.worxware.com/

Comment: @Bob I want the answer specifically for my configuration

Comment: @AndrewCaulfield I just want to know if it is possible to set up XAMPP to so that I can use simple PHP mail() function. I don't want to use a 3rd party application.

Comment: @ littleibex there is no other answer than to have a working smtp server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use PHP mailer and not configure SMTP on your machine or you can follow this instructions to configure sendmail with **GMAIL**. 
I like option 2 :) (Just for fun). Of course the first option is easier.

1. First go to the path that you installed Xampp application. By default it is `C:\xampp\`.
2. Then we need to find the `php.ini` file which contains the
   configurations belong to PHP. This file by default is located at
   `C:\xampp\php\php.ini`. Open it using any text editor like notepad.
3. Using search in the editor try to find `sendmail_path`. There should
   be two of them. One is commented using a `;` (semicolon) in the
   beginning of the line , and the other one is not commented. Comment
   the one that is active and active the one is commented. After the
   edit it should looks like below... (Similar)
       `sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
       ; XAMPP: Comment out this if you want to work with mailToDisk,...
       ;sendmail_path="C:\xampp\mailtodisk\mailtodisk.exe"`
4. Save the `php.ini` file and restart the Apache process. This is
   necessary for the configuration to take place.
5. Next navigate to the sendmail directory. By default it should be
   located at `C:\xampp\sendmail` and open the `sendmail.ini` in the
   text editor.
6. Now we need to set the configuration for the mail server. For this
   case I chose Gmail. The SMTP address of Gmail is: `smtp.gmail.com`
   and the SMTP port for Gmail is **587**.
7. Find `smtp_server` and write the Gmail SMTP address in front of
   that.
8. Find `smtp_port` and write the Gmail SMTP port in front of that.
9. Scroll down , you should be able to see `auth_username` &
   `auth_password`. Put your gmail username in front of  auth_username
   and put the password in front of auth_password .
10. Save and now you are good to send mail from local host.

    - Note that your PHP mail function should have "from" header,otherwise your mail will not go through.
    - Also remember the that the destination will receive the mail from your Gmail address not from the address you put in your PHP code.